# URI Rest com HttpServlet

Tags: java, java-ee, rest, servlet, http-request

Eaí galera, estou desenvolvendo um mini framework para fins de estudos, usando o pattern front controller em java, e me deparei com o seguinte problema.

Antes de mais nada vou explicar como está funcionando.

Eu embuti o servidor jetty dentro do framework, quando eu starto minha aplicação(usando o mini-framework) ele vai varrer as classes do meu projeto verificar se existe duas anotações que eu criei nas minhas classes que são `@Rest` (define que a classe é um controller) e `@Get` (faz o mapeamento da request) e joga em um hashMap com o mapeamento como chave e a classe controller como valor.

```
@Rest
public class UserController {

    @Get("/books")
    public String getBook() {
        Book book = new Book();
        book.setAuthor("NetoDevel");
        book.setTitle("RileyFramework");
        book.setPrice(0.0d);
        return JsonReturn.toJson(book);
    }

    @Get("/book/:id")
    public String findOne(String id) {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Quando eu recebo a requisição, jogo ela na key do meu map e pego o valor que é a classe controller e instancio e invoco o metodo beleza?

Até aqui tudo bem funcionando perfeitamente, mas eu quero definir parametros na minha URI, na arquitetura REST.

Formato que eu quero implementar:

```
http://localhost:8080/books/:id
```

e não

```
http://localhost:8080/books?id=1
```

Minha pergunta é: Como pegar lá no meu servlet que está implementado o valor de `:id` ?

Eu posso ter mais de um param nesse formato abaixo:

```
http://localhost:8080/books/:id/author/:id
```

Segue o link do projeto no github:
https://github.com/NetoDevel/riley-framework

Comment: A resposta te ajudou ou precisa de mais detalhes?

Answer (score 0):

Obtenha o mapa com todos os parâmetros enviados no `request` através do seguinte código:

```
Map pathVariables = (Map) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE);
```

Comment: Não funcionou e essa classe HandlerMapping é do spring? a ideia é implementar o próprio.

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto Entendi, então veja este link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8715566/5230740.

Comment: eu até tinha visto já essa pergunta, mas é algo difícil de manipular por que ele faz split por barra, vai ficar difícil saber quem é os parâmetros na uri. ex: /books/1/author/1 quando eu fizer o split ele vai quebrar em 4 índices books, 1, author, 1 blz? eai como saber quem é os param da uri?

Comment: Em cada URI tu tem um formato esperado. Neste caso, os param é o book=indice[1] e author=indice[3]